# How to get database information from Firebase database once

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've looked everywhere, and no place has given me a satisfactory answer; how do I just simply retrieve data from the Firebase Database when I want it? I don't want to syncronize the data, I just want to get the data when I call for it. Various attempts using once() have failed entirely, not getting me close at all. Is it even possible or is Firebase just not designed for what I'm trying to do?

EDIT: Minimal example of what I want to do:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("location1");
let intendedValue = "Data not Gathered";
ref.once("value").then( function(snapshot) {
  intendedValue = snapshot.val();
});
console.log(intendedValue);
```

Where my firebase database has the structure:

```
projectFolder:
    location1:
        datapoint1: "dataValue1";
```

So you'd think this would log "dataValue1", but instead it logs "Data not Gathered" as if ref.once() never even ran.

Comment: Post your code, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once worked fine for me.

Comment: Try using on, like so: on('value', function(snap){
      snap.forEach(function (childsnap){ ...etc

Comment: It's asynchronous, so you can't do that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6680611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the call to

`ref.once("value").then( function(snapshot) {
  intendedValue = snapshot.val();
});`

is basically a callback, so the moment you log the output, the line `intendedValue = snapshot.val();` is not even run yet.

You can try this

```
 ref.once("value").then( function(snapshot) {
  intendedValue = snapshot.val();
  console.log(intendedValue);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function fire_base_db(){ 

           var ref = firebase.database().ref();
       ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
console.log(snapshot.val());

}, function (error) {
console.log("Error: " + error.code);
     });}
```

snapshot.val() contains the value of your databse
you can store the value of snapshot.val() in a variable and send it to another function